# How to create a JSON file from a NDB database using Python

Tags: json, google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I would like to generate a simple json file from an database.

I am not an expert in parsing json files using python nor NDB database engine nor GQL.

- What is the right query to search the data? see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries
- How should I write the code to generate the JSON using the same schema as the json described here below?

Many thanks for your help

Model Class definition using NDB:

```
# coding=UTF-8 
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import logging

class Albums(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual Event entry with content and date."""

    SingerName = ndb.StringProperty()
    albumName = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Expected output:

```
{
"Madonna": ["Madonna Album", "Like a Virgin", "True Blue", "Like a Prayer"],
"Lady Gaga": ["The Fame", "Born This Way"],
"Bruce Dickinson": ["Iron Maiden", "Killers", "The Number of the Beast", "Piece of Mind"]
}
```

Comment: Here's what you need to do. 1) Query the Albums entities from the datastore 2) Iterate over them to form the data structure you desire (ie a python dictionary where the values are lists) 3) use json.dumps() method to parse to JSON.

Comment: Hi Gwyn, thanks for the info but do you have a piece of code? I am not used with all those data types like dictionary.

Comment: I can easily provide code, but that would be too easy - I'd encourage to you to have a go first!

Comment: Done !

Using a list and a dictionary. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be fast and optimal

Comment: Iirc ndb models have a to dict method....

Comment: @PaulCollingwood ndb models do have a to dict method, however, the json structure specified in the question is not possible using this method.

Comment: For completeness, I have added an answer with a solution to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For consistency, model names should by singular (Album not Albums), and property names should be lowercase_with_underscores:

```
class Album(ndb.Model):
    singer_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    album_name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

To generate the JSON as described in your question:

1) Query the Album entities from the datastore:

```
albums = Album.query().fetch(100)
```

2) Iterate over them to form a python data structure:

```
albums_dict = {}
for album in albums:
    if not album.singer_name in albums_dict:
        albums_dict[album.singer_name] = []
    albums_dict[album.singer_name].append(album.album_name)
```

3) use json.dumps() method to encode to JSON.

```
albums_json = json.dumps(albums_dict)
```

Alternatively, you could use the built in to_dict() method:

```
albums = Album.query().fetch(100)
albums_json = json.dumps([a.to_dict() for a in albums])
```